# Applying ucwords(strtolower(name)) to form data before submitting to DB in CakePHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

Assume a user fills a form and puts his name like AndReW(Mixed lower and uppercase), I want to get this form data, convert it to a form like this Andrew, and then submit it to the database.... I dont want to submit it in this form AndReW, instead like this Andrew..... (I know i can use ucwords(strtolower(AndReW)), but where exactly i'm I supposed to put this code in CakePHP)

I tried ucwords(strtolower(field_name)) in the model(in virtual fields), but it didn't work out.. Where exactly should I put this code? In the model or??

Comment: What happens if their name is MaryAnn McGregor-O'Sullivan? :)

Comment: This is an exception for this system users in the geographical region it's going to be used

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out...
Added this code to the controller action

if(isset($this->data['modelName']['first_name']) && $this->data['modelName']['first_name'] != '')
{
$this->request->data['modelName']['first_name']= ucwords(strtolower($this->data['modelName']['first_name']));
}

This inserts first_name in the database in the desired case of the letters....And it worked out